Does Queen's Ransom apply to Hera Boons recieved afterwards?
The description for the Duo Boon Queen's Ransom states:

Give up al your Boons of Zeus. For each, raise the level of all your Boons of Hera.

If I take Queen's Ransom then get another Hera boon afterwards, will that Boon get the extra levels?
